# How can we match or join headerdatecolumns(Horizontal) with sql table(Vertical) Wpf

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

below code not matching the Headerdatecolumns with sql inam1(Table) Indate Column, I am not able to fix this problem someone help me to fix this problem
this screenshot is the datatable
[image]
this screenshot is inam(table)
[image]
this screenshot is giving result
[image]

```
 Class MainWindow
Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\BUTTONFORMWPF1 - COPY\BUTTONFORMWPF1\NEWDATABASE.MDF;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True")
Private Sub Button_Click_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim table As DataTable = New DataTable("record")
    Dim col = New DataGridTextColumn()
    col.Header = "Column1"
    col.Binding = New Binding("[0]")
    dg.Columns.Add(col)
    col = New DataGridTextColumn()
    col.Header = "Column2"
    col.Binding = New Binding("[1]")
    dg.Columns.Add(col)
    col = New DataGridTextColumn()
    Dim startDate As Date = CType(dtpStartDate.SelectedDate, DateTime)
    Dim endDate As Date = CType(dtpEndDate.SelectedDate, DateTime)
    While startDate <= endDate
        Dim NewColumn As New DataGridTextColumn()
        NewColumn.Header = startDate.ToShortDateString()
        NewColumn.Binding = New Binding("[2]")
        dg.Columns.Add(NewColumn)
        startDate = startDate.AddDays(1)
    End While
    Dim rows As List(Of Object) = New List(Of Object)()
    Dim value As String()
    value = New String(2) {}
    value(0) = "ID"
    value(1) = "Name"
    value(2) = "AM"
    rows.Add(value)
    Dim sda As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("Select datatest1.ID, datatest1.Name, inam1.AM from datatest1 inner join inam1 On datatest1.ID=inam1.ID", connection)
    For i As Integer = 0 To table.Columns.Count
        sda.Fill(table)
        rows.Add(table(i))
    Next i
    dg.ItemsSource = rows
End Sub
```

End Class

below is the xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:project1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="dg" CanUserAddRows="True"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="293,153,122,120"  >
    </DataGrid>
    <DatePicker x:Name="dtpStartDate" Grid.Row="0"    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="53,177,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127"/>
    <DatePicker x:Name="dtpEndDate"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="47,241,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="139"/>
    <Button x:Name="Button" Click="Button_Click_1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="78,310,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110"/>       
</Grid>
```

Comment: (Incidentally, `sda.Fill(table)` should be before the loop because you only need to call it once, and `CType(dtpStartDate.SelectedDate, DateTime)` might as well be `dtpStartDate.SelectedDate` because it is already a DateTime?.)

Comment: thank you so much for reply I'm working as per your suggestion

Comment: For p = 1 To table.Columns.Count - 1
            Dim name1 As String = dg.Columns(p).Header
            Dim aaa As String = "Select datatest1.ID, datatest1.Name from datatest1 "
            Dim query As String = aaa
            Dim sda As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("where dg.name1=inam1.Indate ", connection) how can use "where" condition to match dates my code is not working